# .Net core console app: The dependency MySQL.Data.Core >= 7.0.4-IR-191 could not be resolved

Tags: mysql, .net-core

I've created a test .Net core console application with Visual studio 2015.

A simple console app that communicates with a MySQL db. In debug mode the app runs fine.

When I'm deploying it to Ubuntu (version 16.04) and try to run, I'm receiving the next error:

> .net core deploy on Ubuntu -> error NU1001: The dependency MySql.Data.Core >= 7.0.4-IR-191 could not be resolved

I did a **dotnet restore** and no problems when restoring the packages, only when I'm executing the **dotnet run** the problem is produced!

Any help, perhaps the package `MySql.Data.Core` is not Linux compliant?

[image: error]

[image: version]

```
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "copyToOutput": {
          "include": "appsettings.json"
        }
      },

      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        },
        "MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-IR-191",
        "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.4-IR-191"
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
          "imports": [
            "dnxcore50",
            "portable-net452+win81"
          ]
        }
      }
    }`
```

Comment: [That package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Core/) has been unlisted. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: On second thought, it's weird that `restore` works, but `run` doesn't. Could you try running `restore` again? If that doesn't help, delete `~/.nuget` then then run `restore` once more.

Comment: In the latest pre version `MySql.Data.Core` was rename to just `MySql.Data`. Update to this version `7.0.5-IR21` and that should work.